# GCC optimizes sinl and cosl to sincosl

Tags: gcc, optimization, libc, trigonometry

I'm seeing behaviour when compiling with GCC that implies GCC is smart enough to optimize calls in the same "scope" (I use the term loosely here as the scope is wider than what C++ strictly refers to as a scope) to sin and cos into a single call to sincos.

Specifically, for a `long double x`, `sinl(x)` and `cosl(x)` get optimized to a `sincosl(x, x)` call.

I'm pretty sure this is what's happening as I can comment out either sin or cos and get a call to just cos or sin respectively.  Similarly if I change the parameter then, again, I get separate sin and cos calls.

This is an issue for me as the C library I'm linking against doesn't implement sincosl.  So I really do want the individual functions.

Is my assertion correct?  Can someone point me to documentation for this behaviour?  Can it be disabled?

FYI I'm using:

> i686-nacl-gcc.exe --version
>   x86_64-nacl-gcc (GCC) 4.4.3 20141209 (Native Client r14192, Git Commit 7faaabb9f10e6dcae5f2b799da43e236e65cda95)
>   Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

however I don't expect this to be version specific.  Likely generic GCC behaviour (possibly arch/target specific I guess).

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You might also be interested in this [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46926).

Comment: Ha, thanks. I just found that as well. I can't use -ansi as the project has no chance under those settings.  MCVE might be tricky as I am using a non-standard toolchain.  I can potentially try to repo with an off the shelf version but no promises about the speed at which I do that :(.

Comment: I'm just experimenting with various "workarounds".  I found adding 2 * M_PI to one argument works :).  Not sure I'm particularly happy with that though!

Comment: Did you try using the `-fno-builtin-sincos` flag? The bionic library has a [workaround](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libm/sincos.c) that you might be interested in too.

Comment: Yeah, that flag didn't help.  The way I read the GCC bug report though implied it wouldn't.  The bionic workaround is interesting.  I'd wondered about something like that but wasn't sure how to prevent the recursion.  Will give that a go.  I managed to make something work at a single call site with some use of operator~ but that would need to be done at all call sites.  Bionic's is a generic solution so hopefully it'll work.

Comment: Okay, seems to have worked.  I'll write an answer for others.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments to my original post fo some background on the answer.  Seemingly the best "fix" was to use a Bionic type workaround:

https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libm/sincos.c